# SwiftUI: Animate offset to slide in from off screen

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui

I'm trying to animate in a view the bottom of its parent view. This is relatively easy to do by animating the offset, like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isShowingBanner = true

    var bannerOffset: CGFloat {
        isShowingBanner ? 0 : 60
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()

                BannerView()
                    .offset(y: bannerOffset)
            }
            .border(Color.black, width: 1.0)
            .clipped()


            Spacer()

            Button("Toggle Banner") {
                withAnimation {
                    isShowingBanner.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: Tapping the toggle button animates the offset]

The glaringly obvious problem is that this just uses an arbitrary value for the animated offset, and this quickly breaks when considering dynamic type

[image: the animated offset is less than the height of the view]

My question is:

Is there a way to properly determine the height of `BannerView` to correctly adjust this animation. Or is there a better way to achieve this effect?

Thanks all

Comment: The images are gifs, tap to see them in action

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done just with transition, like

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isShowingBanner = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()

                if isShowingBanner {
                    BannerView()
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))  // << here !!
                }
            }
// >> empty container should not shrink !!
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) 
            .border(Color.black, width: 1.0)
            .clipped()


            Spacer()

            Button("Toggle Banner") {
                withAnimation {
                    isShowingBanner.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing thanks - definitely the easiest solution. I got around the container issues by changing it to a ZStack, and adding a clear background. The .infinity caused a crash for me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine the Height of the BannerView() You can use GeometryReader. I have created BannerView() Just for example bellow : -

```
   struct BannerView() : View {

        @Binding var height : CGFloat

        var body: some View {
            VStack{
               GeometryReader { proxy in
                  Rectangle().fill(.green).onAppear {
                      height = proxy.size.height
                  }
               }
            }.frame(height : 100)
        }
   }
```

So, the Binding value will provide height of the bannerView to your MainView(). You can use that to determine your offset.

```
   @State var isShowingBanner = true
   @State var offsetHeight : CGFloat = 0        

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()

                BannerView(height: $offsetHeight)
                    .offset(y: isShowingBanner ? 0 : offsetHeight)
            }
            .border(Color.black, width: 1.0)
            .clipped()


            Spacer()

            Button("Toggle Banner") {
                withAnimation {
                    isShowingBanner.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
```

Hope you found this useful.

Comment: Thanks Namra! Very clean solution